# How to cap the sprayer connection of a kitchen faucet having plastic tubes?

Tags: plumbing

It is a MOEN 87999SRS faucet, with plastic tubes and the sprayer has a plastic quick connect feature.

Comment: Have you contacted Moen to see if they make a cap? Maybe they will sell you a piece with the quick connect on it - you can cap the other end, then plug that into the quick connect under your sink.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://www.moen.com/products/Moen/Moen-Side-Spray-Plug-Service-Kit/143530